# Set max_input_var on 1and1 Server for a Prstashop 1.6

Tags: php, prestashop-1.6

I have a Prestashop 1,6 with 1and1 as hosting Service and cant use the Translation Service in the Backend because of the max_input_vars settings.

Warning! Your PHP configuration limits the maximum number of fields allowed in a form: 5000 for max_input_vars.
Please ask your hosting provider to increase this limit to 5271 at least, or you will have to edit the translation files.

I tryed to set the max_input_vars settings to 6000 and didnt get a error on the server but it wont work has someone a solution to fix it or knows how to change it?

P.S. here is the PHP file i used

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('max_input_vars', 6000);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have shared hosting then instead of **php.ini** you have create a file name **.user.ini** and 
max_input_vars=6000; 
and upload on root. it will take time to reflect changes based on server settings.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best way to do this is asking directly to 1and1 because is probable that you don't have permissions to change this feature of PHP.

Also, you have another options:

1. File .htaccess: [externar link](http://help.1and1.com/hosting-c37630/scripts-and-programming-languages-c85099/php-c37728/change-php-directives-a660257.html)
2. Make a php.ini file in the root of the installation and add this:

   max_input_vars=6000;

Hope it helps you.